# wordpress change icon colors on hover state

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have some social media icons that I want to change color when I hover on them. I just can't get it to work though.

My code is this -

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );

// add action with variabile in url to share
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','my_social_btn');
function my_social_btn() {
  echo '<div class="my-custom-social">
  <div class = "facebook-icon"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$current_url.'" class="social fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a> </div>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='.$current_url.'" class="social tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
 <a href="
https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media=[post-img]&url='.$current_url.'" class="social tw"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
 </div>
';
}
```

I thought if I give the facebook icon it's own div class I can use the below css, but it doesn't work

```
.facebook-icon:hover {

 color: blue!important;
}
```

Comment: It depends if your icon is in svg. Then you can use for example `fill: blue`. If its normal image then you need to prepare another image and swaps them or you could play with `filter: `, which have couple of functions that may or may not help you generate blue...

Comment: it's an icon I think fa fa-facebook

Comment: Change the statement to background-color: blue !important and see if that works.

Comment: no that makes the backrgound blue, but doesn't change the 'f' to blue - the url is https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/product/sunflower-and-red-rose-bouquet/

Comment: oh my bad. I don really use <i> so thats why. But I should ! The icons on the website that you provide are changing to blue. I see another thing. Your css class is diffrent then in your html... in your html its `fa fa-facebook-f` and you show `.facebook-icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css should look like this

```
.facebook-icon:hover a i {

   color: blue!important;
}
```

Comment: Do you know why if I click on it.. it doesn't share the page on facebook properly? It just opens a page with a share button.. which doesn't do anything?

Comment: Oh I dont really now what is the problem so hard to say.

Comment: Okay no problem. Thanks!!